# Poisson and conditional probability

Tags: combinatorics, probability-distributions

We have two events A and B.

$A_k$ is the event in which $k$ particles are created.

$B_k$ is the event in which $k$ particles are observed.

The creation of articles follows a Poisson distribution 
$P(A_k)=\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda}$.

The observations are independent and the probability that one particle is observed is $p$.

Now I have to find out

a) $P(B_x|A_y)$

b) $P(B_x\cup A_y)$

c) $P(B_x)$

The tasks should built upon the previous ones. That's where I am confused. isn't c) just $p^x$? I also am not sure about the other parts.

b) follows from a) using the formula for conditional probability.

Is a) binomial? 
$\binom{y}{x}p^x(1-p)^{y-x}$

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You're right about a) and b).

I suspect you mean $P(B_x\cap A_y)$ in b)? If you do mean $P(B_x\cup A_y)$, you'll need $P(B_x)$ from c) to calculate $P(B_x\cup A_y)=P(B_x)+P(A_y)-P(B_x\cap A_y)$.

No, the answer to c) isn't just $p^x$. Particles are observed with rate $\lambda p$, so $P(B_x)=\frac{(\lambda p)^k}{k!}\mathrm e^{-\lambda p}$.

Comment: You recently posted a superb answer to a question about 2-coloring the elements of a family of 15-sets.  I think the original poster might have deleted the question.  I would like to see it again.  Would you please visit https://math.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/6622 and send me the link to the deleted post?

Comment: @MJD: Sure: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3452941. In fact I voted to undelete the question, but no one has added their vote so far.

Answer (score 1):

Also I get Joriki's result.

If you do not guess immediately the result for point (c), try to compute:

$p(B_x)=\sum_{y=x}^{+\infty}p(B_x|A_y)p(A_y)$

This way you would exploit the previous result. The computation is a good exercise ;)